# Bower error tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error

Tags: node.js, sockets, permissions, proxy, bower

I'm behind a corporate proxy, I've set my HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY env var to

```
http://username:password@proxyname:port/
```

doing console.log(process.env) output these var correctly. npm is working, I got bower with it and it(bower) was working fine but since I restarted windows XP I'm always getting :

```
bower error tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error
```

I don't think there's anything new on the proxy side. I've already tried reseting those vars, restarting everything... Any sugestion ?

Comment: It's definitely a proxy issue, everything is working fine when I'm not behind proxy. And everything else is working, npm, maven ... and it was working ! Since I restarted XP it keeps saying this. I don't even know what to check, that's why I'm posting a question here so that people can tell me what to check, possible explanations, that sort of stuff... yeah it's probably the fault of the question if you don't have a clue.

Comment: Also, I've tried uninstalling bower, clearing npm cache and install again. I'm using node v0.10.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't know why but clearing an .npmrc file in my home fixed it.

Comment: No need to clear .npmrc file. just open it in notepad and check weather this file contains following params currect ot not...


proxy = http://UNAME:PASSWORD@PROXTIP:PORT/
strict-ssl = false
https-proxy = https://UNAME:PASSWORD@PROXTIP:PORT/

--Make sure thar -ssl is false..

Answer (score 4):

If changing the proxy settings as pointed out by Vipul is not sufficient also change the registry:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Answer (score 2):

Following command work for me

```
npm config set proxy "http://domain\username:password@servername:port/"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue with corporate proxy ON.

The solution is you just need to set system environment variables 'http_proxy' & 'https_proxy' to http://username:password@proxyname:port/

No need to clear .npmrc file.

Its a clear proxy issue and not a node issue. :)