# Error in installing express either using package.json file or without using package.json file

Tags: json, node.js, express

I am trying to install express in my windows terminal by following the instruction mentioned in express website guide

1 First I created a directory node and inside that package.json file.

my package.json is as follows

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "description": "hello world test app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.x"
  }
}
```

then I tried to run the command

```
npm install
```

but getting the following error

```
E:\myFindings\nodejs_programs\node>npm install
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.4.8.tgz
npm ERR! Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\tunnel.js:161:17)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:185:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1320:9)
npm ERR!     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
npm ERR!     at Socket._destroy.self.errorEmitted (net.js:329:14)
npm ERR!     at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
npm ERR!  { [Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd E:\myFindings\nodejs_programs\node
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.0
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.32
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! message tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! Error: socket hang up
npm ERR!     at createHangUpError (http.js:1253:15)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketCloseListener (http.js:1304:23)
npm ERR!     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
npm ERR!     at Socket._destroy.destroyed (net.js:358:10)
npm ERR!     at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
npm ERR!  { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd E:\myFindings\nodejs_programs\node
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.0
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.32
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! message socket hang up
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     E:\myFindings\nodejs_programs\node\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I am unable to understand what is the problem, please help me to sort out

I even try to install express without using the .json file but getting the same error

contents of my npm config list

```
E:\myFindings\nodejs_programs\node>npm config list
; cli configs

; userconfig C:\Users\sudipkumars\.npmrc
https-proxy = "http://sudip:sudip7@proxy:8086/"
proxy = "http://sudip:sudip7@proxy:8086/%20strict-ssl%20=%20false"
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"

; builtin config C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc
prefix = "C:\\Users\\sudipkumars\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node install prefix = C:\Program Files
; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
; cwd = E:\myFindings\nodejs_programs\node
; HOME = C:\Users\sudipkumars
; 'npm config ls -l' to show all defaults.
```

I tried your suggestion

> npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

and output is

```
E:\myFindings\nodejs_programs\node>npm install express
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.4.8.tgz
npm ERR! Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT
npm ERR!     at errnoException (dns.js:31:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:123:16)
npm ERR!  { [Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT] code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND', syscall: 'getaddrinfo' }
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
```

Comment: Proxy? Could this be the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324438/bower-error-tunneling-socket-could-not-be-established-cause-parse-error

Answer (score 3):

In terms of understanding the issue. The problem lies with your computer not being able to establish a connection with: https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.4.8.tgz

It is attempting to use the HTTP GET Method to retrieve the file from the server at the NPM registry but it seems it is timing out:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.4.8.tgz
npm ERR! Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT
```

This could be for a few reasons but I'll mention two main causes:

1. Downtime at npmjs.org, easily checked with http://status.npmjs.org/
2. You're behind a proxy preventing this

Looking at your npm config:

- Unless you have a proxy setup called proxy then this won't work. So clear the proxy variables set
- Set strict SSL to false using `npm config set strict-ssl false`
- If these two don't work, attempt to set the registry to use a non encrypted connection using `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: I even tried to set the proxy, still the effect, and all the solution given in support site are for linux environment

Comment: What is the output of `npm config list`? Post to a pastebin.

Comment: I am putting the result of npm config list below my question, it check it. I don't know whether my proxy setting is correct or not as I have no idea how to set the proxy..

Comment: See response in my answer

Comment: I tried your last option as I don't know anything about proxy setting and the result I am putting below my question

Comment: Ok the last option won't work if strict-ssl is still true so try the following: `npm set https-proxy ""` then `npm set https-proxy ""` then `npm config set strict-ssl false` then try again

Comment: `C:\Users\sudip>npm set https-proxy ""
npm WARN invalid config https-proxy=""
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by issuing the following commands

```
npm config set proxy false
npm cache clean
```

Answer (score 0):

run the following command

```
npm install express
```

Answer (score 0):

work around: `npm config set registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/` works well.

Comment: For future reference I would recommend heavily against using this approach as you're easily subject to a Man in the Middle attack using HTTP to download NPM repos.