# network connect ETIMEDOUT for Protractor instalaltion in a VM

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor

Background_Note: 
I have installed protractor successfully in all global/host machines. But the same does't work in VMs.

That is, this issue appears only in a Windows 7 Virtual machine, not otherwise.
All these machines (VM, hosts and individual machines) have the same Proxy settings, and I have set the same in npm config everywhere.

```html
npm config set proxy http://proxy_server:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy_server:8080
```

---

Now the procedure I tried:

1. I am in a windows 7 remote desktop (VM), logged in as a non administrator user
2. I opened cmd window as administrator.
3. Tried installing protractor as

```html
npm install -g protractor
```

3. This installation fails, log and config lists are attached below.
4. Tried all the possible answers from [Bower error tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324438/bower-error-tunneling-socket-could-not-be-established-cause-parse-error)
   ==> They don't work for me.

```html
C:\Windows\system32>npm config list
; cli configs
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
user-agent = "npm/1.4.28 node/v0.10.33 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\test\.npmrc
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\test\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
; cwd = C:\Windows\system32
; HOME = C:\Users\test
; 'npm config ls -l' to show all defaults.
```

C:\Windows\system32>

Log written at npm-debug.log:

```html
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'protractor',
1 verbose cli   '--registry',
1 verbose cli   'http://registry.npmjs.org/' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.28
3 info using node@v0.10.33
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose cache add [ 'protractor', null ]
6 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="protractor" args=["protractor",null]
7 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
7 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
7 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
7 verbose parsed url   host: null,
7 verbose parsed url   port: null,
7 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
7 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
7 verbose parsed url   search: null,
7 verbose parsed url   query: null,
7 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'protractor',
7 verbose parsed url   path: 'protractor',
7 verbose parsed url   href: 'protractor' }
8 silly lockFile 4f4f4858-protractor protractor
9 verbose lock protractor C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\4f4f4858-protractor.lock
10 silly lockFile 4f4f4858-protractor protractor
11 silly lockFile 4f4f4858-protractor protractor
12 verbose addNamed [ 'protractor', '' ]
13 verbose addNamed [ null, '*' ]
14 silly lockFile 80d5ca5a-protractor protractor@
15 verbose lock protractor@ C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\80d5ca5a-protractor.lock
16 silly addNameRange { name: 'protractor', range: '*', hasData: false }
17 verbose request where is /protractor
18 verbose request registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
19 verbose request id b468ffda57abdf0d
20 verbose url raw /protractor
21 verbose url resolving [ 'http://registry.npmjs.org/', './protractor' ]
22 verbose url resolved http://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
23 verbose request where is http://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
24 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 18:20:15
25 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
26 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
27 info trying registry request attempt 2 at 18:20:47
28 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
29 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
30 info trying registry request attempt 3 at 18:22:08
31 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
32 silly lockFile 80d5ca5a-protractor protractor@
33 silly lockFile 80d5ca5a-protractor protractor@
34 error network connect ETIMEDOUT
34 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
34 error network and is related to network connectivity.
34 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
34 error network
34 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
34 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
35 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
36 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "protractor" "--registry" "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
37 error cwd C:\Windows\system32
38 error node -v v0.10.33
39 error npm -v 1.4.28
40 error syscall connect
41 error code ETIMEDOUT
42 error errno ETIMEDOUT
43 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
When a VM is used and it has certain set of proxies, use the global proxy (which is the root for all others).
So, run these two commands before installing protractor:

```html
C:\Windows\system32>npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
C:\Windows\system32>npm config set proxy http://global.proxy.alcatel-lucent.com:8000
```

Solves the issue